# How to trigger keydown on an element in jasmine unit test

Tags: javascript, jasmine, gruntjs, typescript

I am writing a jasmine unit test for a function that receives 'keydown' event. It's just a plain javascript(not using any framework)

```
var event = document.createEvent('Event');
event.keyCode = 84; 
event.initEvent('keydown');
event.target = $('#selector');
myFunction(event);
```

When I console log the event in myFunction
This is what I get:

```
{"returnValue":true,"timeStamp":1607595872162,"eventPhase":0,"target":null,"defaultPrevented":false,"srcElement":null,"type":"keydown","cancelable":false,"currentTarget":null,"bubbles":false,"cancelBubble":false,"keyCode":84}
```

The 'target' property is null

How do I set the target value?
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're looking to [dispatch the event you created](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent). The MDN article I linked indicates the `target` parameter is used to initialize `target` in the event. In your case, I would do something like:

```
var event = document.createEvent('Event');
event.keyCode = 84; 
event.initEvent('keydown');
$('#selector')[0].dispatchEvent(event);
```

This makes the assumption that you've bound `myFunction` to `#selector`'s `keydown` event via:

```
document.getElementById("selector").addEventListener('keydown', myFunction);
```

or

```
$('#selector').on('keydown', myFunction);
```

If you're not binding the function with an event listener, you could leverage [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) by building a fake event object and passing that fake event to `myFunction`:

```
myFunction({
    type: 'keydown',
    keyCode: 84,
    target: $('#selector')[0]
});
```